# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display selected record and display on the view but am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

I have tried all I could but couldn't resolve it. Please see the code below. I test the connection with the database and it is connected.

```
router.get('/getme', function(req, res, next) {
 db.query('SELECT * FROM STATE', function (err, rs) {
  res.render('getme', {state: rs});
 });
});


<table>
    <tr>
        <td> state id</td>
        <td> state name </td>
    </tr>
    <% state.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.stateid %></td>
        <td><%= item.state_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
</table>
```

**Connection**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createPool({
host: 'localhost',
user: '',
password: '',
database: 'partme',
debug: false

});
```

Comment: Did you try to print `err`? What is its value?

Comment: try `console.log(res)` in your controller db callback

Comment: It means that the value of `state` is `undefined`

Comment: consider having if clause for `state` before having foreach loop

Comment: I have check with the if clause and it is not printing `rs` or `err`. Do you think the error is with the database or how can I fix this please?

Comment: I get this message printing `err`: `{"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"fatal":true}`. I think the mistake is with the database. I add my connection setup up if you have any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(err, rs)
```

maybe your `rs` is `undefined` and `err` is not `undefined` (error when you load from DB)

You should check:

```
if (err) {
    // handle err here
} else {
    res.render('getme', {state: rs});
}
```

Comment: It is true that the `rs` is undefined and `err` is not undefined. I get error message when I check. Please do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You can render other page that you can't find that user,.

Other check `state == undefined` and don't show `table` of info, just say to user that you don't have info about him/her and say `please try again`(or something like that)

Comment: I get this message printing `err`: `{"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"fatal":true}`. I think the mistake is with the database. I add my connection setup up if you have any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have match `user` + `password`, default password is `''`

Comment: See if your mysql server is running or accepting connections ,check for username and pass if you have providde@NAHEEMOLANIYAN

Comment: MySQL is not accepting connection. I have to shutdown my laptop and restart again. Thank you for your help.